# How is this php setter sanitizing the string?

Tags: php, class, getter-setter, sanitization

I'm referencing this code for an assignment where I have to create my own class. I don't understand how this example setter is sanitizing the token string.

I have a feeling that it has to do with the `(?string $newProfileActivationToken):void` part in line 10, but I'm not familiar with that syntax. Does this syntax have a name I can google, and is it performing the sanitizing?

```php
/**
     * mutator method for account activation token
     *
     * @param string $newProfileActivationToken
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException  if the token is not a string or insecure
     * @throws \RangeException if the token is not exactly 32 characters
     * @throws \TypeError if the activation token is not a string
     */
    public function setProfileActivationToken(?string $newProfileActivationToken): void {
        if($newProfileActivationToken === null) {
            $this->profileActivationToken = null;
            return;
        }
        $newProfileActivationToken = strtolower(trim($newProfileActivationToken));
        if(ctype_xdigit($newProfileActivationToken) === false) {
            throw(new\RangeException("user activation is not 
valid"));
        }
        //make sure user activation token is only 32 characters
        if(strlen($newProfileActivationToken) !== 32) {
            throw(new\RangeException("user activation token has to be 32"));
        }
        $this->profileActivationToken = $newProfileActivationToken;
```

I expected to use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`